# Difference in the final letter 'N' of a Nvidia graphic card

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

I'm wondering whether there is difference between a Nvidia GTX560N and a GTX560 graphic card.

What does the N suffix stand for?

Comment: Are you sure it's not an 'M'? In that case it would indicate that the chip is a Mobile GPU. Where did you see an nvidia GTX560N?

Comment: No, it's a 'N', I thought of the M either, but it isn't my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is listed nowhere - neither on the [official NVIDIA site about the GTX 560](http://www.nvidia.de/object/product-geforce-gtx-560-de.html) nor the [Wikipedia page on the 500 Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_500_Series) I assume it's an self-made addition meaning "normal" so you can see it is *not* the mobile/Ti version while you can't be sure if there is no letter (because it might just have been forgotten).

Answer (score 4):

The GPU is not actually called GTX 560N, but EVGA seems to use the letter N to indicate that it is non-Ti (as in their model GTX-560N-B1-1024).